# symfony1 route with negative number or string as id and sfDoctrineRouteCollection

Tags: routes, symfony1

I'm using symfony 1.4, i have a route like this:

```
user_orders:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                UserOrders
    module:               user_orders
    prefix_path:          /orders
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
    requirements: 
      id: \w+
```

i would like to have orders with negative numbers in the ID field, so, when trying to access a url like this `/orders/12/edit` i go to the edit form page, this is ok, but, when accessing an url like `/orders/-1/edit` i get the error `Action "orders/1" does not exist.`, so, i start to try with a string in the id, but when accessing url `/orders/id1/edit` same error appear `Action "orders/id1" does not exist.`, so, the questions is,
is this possible or not? i mean, have a negative number by id or string in the url?
the requirements in the routing config is ok or not?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question, maybe it can help someone else, the fix was simple after a few try, i need to create another route, under the `user_orders` route definition, to override the `user_orders_edit` and `user_orders_update` routes, finally, it looks like this:

```
user_orders:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                UserOrders
    module:               user_orders
    prefix_path:          /orders
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
  requirements: {id: \w+}
user_orders_edit:
  url:     /orders/:id/edit.:sf_format
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: UserOrders, type: object }
  param:   { module: user_orders, action: edit, sf_format: html }
  requirements: { sf_method: get, id: \w+ }
user_orders_update:
  url:     /orders/:id.:sf_format
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: UserOrders, type: object }
  param:   { module: user_orders, action: update, sf_format: html }
  requirements: { sf_method: put, id: \w+ }
```

i couldn't use a negative number in the url, but i was able to use a string like `/orders/id123/edit`

done it

Answer (score 0):

To revive an old question,  but I just stumbled upon this problem myself:

the `requirements` is not a child of `options` but a sibling (same level as options). So this will work:

```
user_orders:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                UserOrders
    module:               user_orders
    prefix_path:          /orders
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
  requirements: {id: \w+}
```